# Rotate Labels in GWT

Tags: css, gwt, rotation

I want to rotate a simple GWT-Label. Is there any option?

I have set up a simple css-style:

```css
.rotate{

/* Abs positioning makes it not take up vert space */
position: relative;
top: 330;
left: 330;

/* Border is the new background */
background: none;



-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
-moz-transform:    rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform:     rotate(90deg);
-o-transform:      rotate(90deg);
}
```

But it didn't work when I add the style to the label.

Comment: Please post an example of how you applied this style, as it definitely works for me.

Comment: I add the label to the absolutePanel:
`Label rotated= new Label("this must be rotated");
   rotated.addStyleName("rotate");
   add(rotated);`

Comment: Use your browser to inspect the element and make sure it actually got that style applied. Is the CSS file definitely included in the module's HTML file?

Comment: at the moment i test it in chrome and all works fine :) But in the IE it doesn't work for me

Comment: I'd bet your problem is related to using an unsupported CSS command. You are probably using something below IE9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS transforms only work (using browser-specific CSS properties) in Chrome, Opera, Firefox, Safari and IE9+. You're using the proper transform syntax for all of these. For older versions of IE, you can transform like this:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to make a vertical text, or any other text transformations I recommend to consider using SVG graphics.